# php move_uploaded_file function not working but record save in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, dom

i've design codes to upload image and data information in hosted server database. The record information save in table. But image not move to server folder. I also try `rename()` and `Copy()` but not working. 
The strange thing is that i've designed four upload information forms(a,b,c and d) but d is not working. all 3 are working fine. same codes are in all files.

my codes are in files

`d.php`

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<!--Form 1-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 center" id="shahster">
<div class="panel panel-default shadow">
<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"&gt;Shashter Form</h3></div>
<div class="panel-body">    

        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="<?php $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ;?&gt;
/dashboard/other/other_sbt.php"&gt;
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="name"&gt;Article Title Name</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="nametxt" placeholder="Enter Title Name" /></div></div>            

        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="desc">Description</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9"><textarea rows="3" class="form-control" id="desc" name="desctxt" placeholder="Description"></textarea></div></div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="upload">Upload:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9"><input id="upload" class="file"  type="file" name="upimage" data-min-file-count="1" /></div></div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-3" for="type">Choose options</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9"> 
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="taksalitxt" value="taksali" /> Taksali</label></div></div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-3">Feature Product</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9"><input type="checkbox" name="fproducttxt" value="fproduct"></div></div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset" /></div></div>
        </form>

</div><!--Panel Body Close-->
</div><!--Panel default Close-->
</div><!--End of Col6 Form-->
</div><!--End of form Row-->
</div><!--End of Container-->
```

`d_submit.php`

```
    ob_start();
//global $target_path;
include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/dashboard/other/crudfrm.php');  
$shaobj = new shashter();
if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){

        $name1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nametxt']);
        if(isset($_POST['taksalitxt'])){
            $taksali = true;
        }
        else {
            $taksali = false;
        }
        if(isset($_POST['fproducttxt'])){
        $fproduct = true;
        }
        else {
            $fproduct = false;
        }
        $desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['desctxt']);

            //*************IMAGE MANIPULATION


    if(isset($_FILES['upimage'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['upimage']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['upimage']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['upimage']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['upimage']['type'];   
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['upimage']['name'])));
    $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png");        
    if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
    }
    if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
    }               
    if(empty($errors)==true){
         // Place it into your "uploads" folder mow using the move_uploaded_file() function
        $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'uploadimg/other/full/'.$file_name);
        //echo $moveResult;
        echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploadimg/other/thumb/".$file_name."<br>";
        //exit();      

        echo "<br>Success";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
    }
}/*isset condition close*/

$thumb_path = "thumb/".$file_name;  
$full_path = "full/".$file_name;    
        //*************IMAGE MANIPULATION END
    if($moveResult) {
        echo "File Uploaded Successfull!";
    }else{
   echo "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";
   // unlink($file_tmp); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
  //  exit();
}
//unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder 

        // ---------- Include Universal Image Resizing Function --------
include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/dashboard/image_resize_lib.php");
$target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploadimg/other/full/$file_name";
$resized_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploadimg/other/thumb/$file_name";
$wmax = 200;
$hmax = 150;    

//echo "<br><br>../../uploadimg/shashter/full/".$file_name;
ak_img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $fileExt);
// ----------- End Universal Image Resizing Function -----------
// Display things to the page so you can see what is happening for testing purposes
echo "The file named <strong>$fileName</strong> uploaded successfuly.<br /><br />";
echo "It is <strong>$fileSize</strong> bytes in size.<br /><br />";
echo "It is an <strong>$fileType</strong> type of file.<br /><br />";
echo "The file extension is <strong>$fileExt</strong><br /><br />";
echo "The Error Message output for this upload is: $fileErrorMsg";

//#################################### SAVE  RECORD USING CLASS LIBRARY ####################################
    $register = $shaobj->createpro($name1, $desc, $taksali, $fproduct, $thumb_path, $full_path );

    if($register){
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file

             echo "<script>alert('Product Added Successful')</script>";
                     header('Location: http://example.com/dashboard/admindashboard.php');
                     exit();
                }else{
                    echo "<script>alert('Product Not Added Successful')</script>";
                }
```

Comment: The `PHP` closing tag in your `form` tag is encoded: `?&gt;`

Comment: yes i encode it because problem to post on stackoverflow

Comment: Ok, could you please check if your `move_uploaded_file` call is reached? BTW: You are moving your file to `uploadimg/other/full/` but in your `echo` you are using `uploadimg/other/thumb/`.

Comment: it's just echo for check $file_name variable carry file name with path. this line has not fuction just echo.

Comment: Is your `move_uploaded_file` call reached? Do you have the required permissions to write to the directory `uploadimg/other/full/`? What's the value of `$moveResult` after `move_uploaded_file` call? Please also check your `php_error_log` for warnings, notices etc.

Comment: permissions to write to the directory is ok. i think $moveResult show false that way its not upload image to directory. Please can you explain how i check warning notices.

Answer (score 0):

Add one check inside your if condition and put your code inside try catch block so that you will get the proper error messages. Try with this and edit as per your need :).

```
try {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (isset($_FILES['upimage'])) {

            $errors = array();
            $file_name = $_FILES['upimage']['name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['upimage']['size'];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['upimage']['tmp_name'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['upimage']['type'];
            $file_ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['upimage']['name'])));
            $extensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
            if (in_array($file_ext, $extensions) === false) {
                $errors[] = "extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
            }
            if ($file_size > 2097152) {
                $errors[] = 'File size must be excately 2 MB';
            }
            if (empty($errors) == true) {
                // Place it into your "uploads" folder mow using the move_uploaded_file() function
                $dirPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploadimg/other/full/';
                if (!file_exists($dirPath)) {
                    mkdir($dirPath, 0777, true);
                }
                $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $dirPath . $file_name);
                //echo $moveResult;
                echo $dirPath . $file_name . "<br>";
                //exit();    
                echo "<br>Success";
            } else {
                print_r($errors);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am considering you have all file write permission for the above code. Have a Happy coding :).